# How to Access Device Settings

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I need your help. I am developing a mobile app using ionicframework. I have a popup that shows up on app start if the user's device is not connected to the internet. How do I make th =e popup button direct the user to device setting?

Answer (score 0):

Try webintent.startActivity with action equals `"android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"` it should work same as android java:

`context.startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need for that to develop a new cordova module with proper Android code 
There is no existing Cordova plugin for that yet.
BTW, if you find one, I'm interested ;)

The android code to open the LOCATION settings is the following :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent,1);
```

But that will not work for iOS (as it need proper iOS code), not windows